# Bluestone pavers for front stoop?

Tags: stone, mortar, bluestone

In the fall I made a simple front stoop.  It is 24 inches by 48 inches.  That size feels just right.  It has some brick-shaped things from Home Depot as the under layer, and then the top layer is eight one-foot-square pavers also from Home Depot.  I stuck everything together with "landscape glue" using a caulking gun.  It was late fall and maybe a little too cold, and now a couple of the square pavers are loose.  I was about to re-attach the loose ones with either the same type of landscape glue or with some quick set mortar (I have some power left over from another project).  But I started to think that maybe two bluestone treads would look better, similar to this:

[image: screenshot from This Old House video]

which I got from a This Old House video.

If I do that, should the two treads (each measuring one foot by four feet) be butted against each other, or should I leave half an inch between, and then put some mortar in between with a "grout bag"?

Also, about the mortar for the treads.  In the [video](https://youtu.be/e7kH_p_qRBo), here's how they stuck the treads on: start with regular mortar, pretty thick.  Then scratch X's in that mortar.  Then add water to some mortar to make a slurry and put some of that on top of the regular mortar layer.  I guess that's to make it easier to get the big heavy tread nice and level.  Is there any simplification possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified installation was indeed possible.  I just used some leftover mortar mix from another project.

When I bought the bluestone the supplier told me to butt them up next to each other.  That worked well.

It's best to place the stones with an assistant, with one person on either side.

The result looks very good.